# Apache ignite loadCache() with filter or predicate conditions with generics

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ignite

I am looking for .net/C# implementation where I can load the cache using Ignite.LoadCache() method to load with certain query operation only. Or to be more specific only load what is needed in cache instead all everything

Right now I am loading cache with `null` as mentioned here [loadCache](http://ttps://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-loadcache-)

Here is my current implementation

```
public List<TV> Where<TK, TV>(Expression<Func<ICacheEntry<TK, TV>, bool>> query)
    {
        var cache =  _ignite.GetCache<TK, TV>(MyLocalCache);

        LoadCache(cache);

        var result = cache.AsCacheQueryable().Where(query);
    }

     private static void LoadCache<TK, TV>(ICache<TK, TV> cache)
    {
        
            cache.LoadCache(null);
    }
```

Also I am using SQL as my 3rd party persistence layer

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this inside your custom ICacheStore<K, V> implementation.

You can control loading by passing custom args to the LoadCache method:

```
    public void LoadCache(Action<object, object> act, params object[] args)
    {

        // no args, yield all values
        if (args == null)
        {
            for (var item in loadAllFromSql())
            {
                act(item.Id, item);
            }
            return;
        }

        // args contains start and count
        int start = (int) args[0];
        int cnt = (int) args[1];

        for (int i = start; i < start + cnt; i++)
        {
            act(new Key(i), new Value(i));
        }
    }
```

And pass that args with #loadCache method optionally using a cache entry filter:

```
// load 10 entities starting from 100
cache.LoadCache(new CacheEntryFilter(), 100, 10);
```

I think passing an Expression as an argument should work for you.

Comment: Okay , I have LoadCache implmeneted for every store. Now question is how cani i pass the expression to `cache.LoadCache` method
It could not find CacheEntryFilter in local directive

I am trying to invoke function like this now,
`cache.LoadCache(new CacheEntryFilter(),query); // Cannot find CacheEntryFilter`

Comment: I don't think you need to use a filter there, it could be set to null instead.. Also, you can pass the whole Expression and it should be serialized properly. Like `Expression<Func<int, bool>> myExp = i => i > 10;` and then `cache.LoadCache(null, myExp)`

Comment: And then you can inspect this argument and cast it back to expression inside your LoadCache method, similar to getting start and count values in the answer